# GNU Grub dual boot screen freezes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I have Dell Precision with windows 10 64bit installed on it. freeing some space and moving from `RAID` to `AHCI` I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04.

sometimes on startup or restart the dual boot screen `GNU grub 2.02` goes black for a *fraction of a second* and returns and after that everything freezes. the arrow key does not work and countdown stops.

the only solution is `ctrl` + `alt` + `del` to restart and most of the times after this restart the problem does not occur.

the only accessories is a wireless Logitech mouse-keyboard connected to USB.
is it a common problem? searching the web saw many grub problems but mostly were receiving an error screen.

Comment: Have you disabled fast startup on Windows?

Comment: @Arun yes it is disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this particular case, it seems that the problem was occurring because of the time system difference between windows and ubuntu.

I noticed whenever I shutdown or restart from windows the next start the problem was happening. the fast start on windows was off. also noticed whenever I use Ubuntu the next booting to windows cause windows to have not a correct time.

therefore I made Ubuntu to use local time

`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock` (*which was an easier solution than making windows use UTC*) and since then I have not faced the issue

Comment: That saved me too. I was going to discard this whole dual boot idea all together because of this. Thanks.